# Logparser - Selecting data in the past 2 weeks

Tags: iis, logging, sql, logparser

I am trying to use LogParser to return the data from my iis log files for the past 2 weeks. When I run the following I get "Error: Syntax Error: : no valid content: expecting opening parenthesis instead of token 'DATEADD(day,-14,'"

```
logparser "SELECT * FROM mylogfile.log WHERE date >= DATEADD(day,-14, GETDATE())" -o:datagrid
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `DATEADD` nor `GETDATE` are valid function names in the LogParser language. You may check function names by running `logparser -h -i:func`.

What you probably want is:

`WHERE date >= SUB(SYSTEM_DATE(), DURATION('14', 'd'))`